# How do I stop "pop-up perspectives" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

It seems like half the actions I perform in Eclipse open up a new perspective, thus covering up the beautifully arranged perspective I've created.  It feels like I'm back in 1998 fighting all these "pop-up perspectives."

Is there a way to prevent new perspectives from opening automatically in Eclipse?  Is there a universal setting that controls this (?) or will I have to change plugin specific settings?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Other than the two that Zoltan mentioned, are there other actions that trigger a new perspective?

Comment: The specific perspective driving me crazy in the "Team Synchronization" perspective that shows up every time I try to sync to a SVN repository.  I didn't mention this in my questions because I wanted to ask if there is a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two preference settings that might help your issue (but not completely solve it):

1. Preferences -> General -> Perspectives: *Open the associated perspective when creating a project*
2. Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives: *Open the associated perspective when launching* and *Open the associated perspective when the application suspends*

However, if you turn down the perspective switches, then you might have to manually switch to the Debug perspective while debugging. That switch makes sense to me, as during debugging I seldom want to traverse the code by the package structure but by the types of the variables and the stack trace. In other words, some switching makes sense (to me at least).

Answer (score 1):

The Team Synchronize perspective switching can be disabled via **Preferences** > **Team** (the option is "Open the associated perspective when..."

I'm pretty sure the default choice is **Prompt** unless you change it at some point in the prompt dialog.